# Test for empty properties with Lodash

Tags: javascript, object, properties, lodash

How can i check if there is empty properties in obj. I use lodash .

```
var obj={
  "DESIGEMPRESA": "CMIP",
  "DSP_DEPT": "",
  "DSP_DIRECAO": ""
}
```

Return true if theres is empty properties and false if all have values.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

```
_.some(obj, function (value) { return value === "" })
```

You can use this, which will return true if there are any empty properties and false when there are none. This can also be made nicer if you're able to use arrow syntax

```
_.some(obj, (value) => value === "")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to check for all possible variations of undefined or falsey values this function works as well

```
function hasAllValues(obj) {
  var allValues = _.values(obj);
  var nonFalseValues = _.compact(allValues);
  return allValues.length === nonFalseValues.length
 }
```

Comment: You don't need to do all that. `_.every(obj)` will return `true` if all of the properties are tuthy and `false` if any of them is falsey. Just reverse those and you get the desired result: `!_.every(object)`. or the more lodash-y way `_.negate(_.every)(obj)`

Comment: Very nice, seems with lodash there is always a one line way of doing things once you find the right function.